# How to add selectively create events & add event created / not created to my Google sheet?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-calendar-api, google-workspace

I want to create a Google sheet that acts as "Scheduler + Logger" of all my meetings & calls.

To do this, I have a created a Google sheet containing all relevant information - I will enter event details & responses in it.

I want to create Google calendar events from this sheet with 2 criteria:

- create only new events, not for rows for which events have been created previously
- create events only for selected rows in Column B

Event should be created only those rows for which these 2 criteria are met.

I am attaching [Sample Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1U4z7Hk4OLia_xp-eogKfcKJoyELi1voTUhXoga3MhmI/edit?usp=sharing)

I found an app script code & tried customizing it for my use case:

```
function create_Events(){

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Meetings / Calls");
  var last_row = sheet.getLastRow();
  var data = sheet.getRange("A2:P" + last_row).getValues();
  var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("rushi@graviti.co.in");
  //Logger.log(data);

  for(var i = 0;i< data.length;i++){
    //index 0 =
    var event = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar().createEvent(
     data[i][2],
     new Date(data[i][12]),
     new Date(data[i][13]),
     {location: data[i][8],guests: data[i][3],sendInvites: true});
    sheet.getRange(i,16).setValues(event.getId());

    
  }

}
```

I am able to create events from this, but I am not able to do this -

- Add success / failure message on each row when the event is created in Column P.
- Create events only for selected rows in Column B when event has not been created previously as per Column P.

Please provide a solution.

Comment: About `Add success / failure message on each row when the event is created in Column P.` and `Create events only for selected rows in Column B when event has not been created previously as per Column P.`, I cannot understand `failure`. When do you want to put `failure`?

Comment: @Tanaike I want to put failure when the event is not created by the script due to any reason. This helps me understand points of failure if any in the data entered, and I can create those events manually as a back up.

Comment: Related question: [Need Help Creating Events From Google Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76457754/1330560)