# Need Help Creating Events From Google Sheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-calendar-api

I have a script that effectively creates google calendar events with a Google Form Response Spreadhseet but I have 2 changes that need to be made before I can consider it fully functional.

As is, the script must be run manually but I would like it to trigger on either a change in a cell or a new row is added.

As is, the script duplicates every every event in the sheet which needs to stop. I have the event ID added to the last column when an event is created.

The script right now will create an event and add the event ID to the last column. I know this ID will be used to fix both my problems using some sort of lookup funtion to know which event needs to be updated when there is a change in the sheet as well as knowing that If there is an event ID in the last row, then the event shouldn't need to created.

By the way I have next to 0 clue what I'm doing, I've only gotten this far using a fuck ton of googling and copy pasting until shit works. I'm not a computer science guy. Just a dude who had an in idea that happens to apparently need to use google scripts.

Function below does work, but again each event is duplicated when it is ran. I expect that to happen because there are no conditions declared to NOT create an event. I just don't know how to properly write what I need it to do.

```
function createcalendarevent() { 
  const sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const cal = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar(); 
  const ss = sh.getActiveSheet();

  let data = ss.getRange(2,1,ss.getLastRow(),7).getValues();
  let event,loc,d1,d2,t;

  for (let i in data){
    event = data[i][3];
    loc = data [i][6];
    d1 = new Date(data[i][4]);
    t = new Date(data[i][5]);
    d1.setHours(t.getHours(),t.getMinutes());
    d2 = new Date(d1.getTime() + 60 * 60000);

    var series = cal.createEvent(event,d1,d2,{location: loc});
    var eventid = series.getId();
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('H2').setValue(eventid);
  }
}
```

Comment: `As is, the script must be run manually but I would like it to trigger on either a change in a cell or a new row is added.` Why not use the installable `onFormSubmit` trigger in the spreadsheet; this will run whenever a new submission is received. If you add [Event Objects ](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit) you can identify the new row and the values on that row.

Answer (score 0):

You have a Google Form that is used to record Calendar events. This is coupled with a Google sheets script which updates Google Calendar based on the details submitted in the form.

You have two unresolved issues:

- triggering
- duplicates every every event in the sheet.

**Trigger**

- The function is bound to your spreadsheet (which is linked to your form)
- Create an installable trigger for function `createcalendarevent` for event type "On form submit".
- this will trigger the function every time a new form submission is recorded.

**Process only one submission - Event Objects**

- `for (let i in data){` - this creates a loop which processes *every* submission *every* time the function is run. This is removed in the answer.
- but how does one know the details of the latest form submission? By using [Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events); read the documentation for [details of the "Form submit" event objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit)

**Note:** Insert the Calendar ID for your calendar or modify for `getDefaultCalendar()`.

---

```
function createcalendarevent(e) { 
  // list all the Event Objects 
  // Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e)) // DEBUG

  const sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sheet = sh.getSheetByName("Form Responses 1")

  // Gets my Stack Exchange calendar
  const calId = "<<Insert Calendar ID>>"
  const cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calId);

  // get the row number of the submission
  const row = e.range.rowStart

  let event,loc,d1,d2,t;
  event = e.values[3];
  loc = e.values[6];
  d1 = new Date(e.values[4]);
  t = new Date(e.values[5]);
  d1.setHours(t.getHours(),t.getMinutes());
  d2 = new Date(d1.getTime() + 60 * 60000);
  Logger.log("DEBUG: row = "+row+", event = "+event+", loc = "+loc+", d1 = "+d1+", t = "+t+", d2 = "+d2)
  var series = cal.createEvent(event,d1,d2,{location: loc});
  var eventid = series.getId();
  sheet.getRange(row,8).setValue(eventid);
}
```

---